# upgraded Amazon EC2 instance and phpmyadmin cannot connect to mysql

Tags: mysql, magento, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

I launched an Amazon EC2 server (micro instance) to host Magento (followed this tutorial: http://blog.masini.com.au/2013/03/01/installing-magento-on-amazon-ec2-hosting-a-simple-guide/). To do so, I also installed mysql, phpmyadmin (for ease of use) and magento 1.8.1.

Initially everything worked fine until basic Magento usage caused mysql to crash. It seems the micro instance (613 mb) is too small for mysql. So I stopped the instance and restarted it with a higher instance (m1.medium) and mysql seems to be working fine ("mysqld (pid  2158) is running...").

However, phpmyadmin does not seem to connect to mysql anymore: #1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server

[magento doesn't work either - report log says: "SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket"]

Comment: Could it be that the new instance has a different public DNS or IP but the previous DNS/IP is still referenced in some configuration?

Comment: possibly - I know the old IP is stored in Magento (when I set it up) but I did not manually input the old IP when setting up phpmyadmin. Is there any way to check/

Comment: I'm not very familiar with phpMyAdmin, but look for a config file named `config.inc.php`.